# const objects as a function parameter

Tags: c++, constants

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class MyClass {
    int x;
  public:
    MyClass(int val) : x(val) {}
    const int& get() const {return x;}
};

void print (const MyClass& arg) {
  cout << arg.get() << '\n';
}

int main() {
  MyClass foo (10);
  print(foo);

  return 0;
}
```

Whether I add a `const` modifier before the instatiatation of MyClass or not, the program successfully compiles (without any warning) and prints `10`. Why can `print` accept a non-`const` argument? Or, in other words, what is the function of the `const` modifier in the function parameter? Why can the formal and actual parameters of a function have different types (or modifiers)?

I have tried both GCC (4.8.2) and Clang (3.4) with `-Wall -std=c++11` on Ubuntu 14.04, and the results were the same (no errors/warnings). I have also searched "c++ const object function" but didn't get anything that looked promising.

Comment: Why shouldn't it accept a non-const argument? It is OK not to change a non-const object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely sane and normal. The object is treated as `const` within your function; it does not matter that it was not originally created to be immutable.

Of course, the opposite is not true!

```
void foo(T& rarr);

int main()
{
   const T lolwut;
   foo(lolwut);   // oops
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` forbids the body of the function from modifying the parameter variable. Both ways compile because you didn't attempt to modify it.

You can overload `const` and non-`const` reference parameters, and the `const` overload will only be chosen if the argument is really `const` (or a type conversion results in a temporary being passed). (For non-reference parameters, `const` seldom makes sense and such overloads may not even be defined.)

Answer (score 0):

All that `const` does in this case is to prevent modification of parameter variable (and in the case of classes, prevent the calling of functions that are not labelled as `const`). `MyClass` may be trivially cast to `const MyClass` because there should be nothing that you can do to a `const MyClass` that you can't do to a non-`const` one. The reverse is not true, of course.

(I say "should" above, because it is of course possible to completely subvert `const` semantics under C++ if you wanted to, so the presence of `const` in a function prototype is really only a hopeful hint rather than a cast-iron compiler-enforced guarantee. But no sensible programmer should be breaking things like that!)